# save firebase phone number to local storage variable

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication, local-storage

```js
'callbacks': {
      signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function(authResult, redirectUrl) {
     //getting the number after login
      debugger;
      var phoneNumber = authResult.user.phoneNumber;
      localStorage.setItem('phoneNumber',  firebase.auth().currentUser.phoneNumber.toString());          
      return true;
    },
      // Called when the user has been successfully signed in.
```

This is the code that I wrote to save the current users phone number to a local storage variable so I can access it from another file. I want the phone number in a string form

```js
 var ML = localStorage.getItem("phoneNumber");
  
 confirm(ML);
```

This is the code that I used to access the local storage variable. For some reason, it keeps saying NULL in the confirm box instead of displaying the phone number. If anyone could help me with this I would really appreciate it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBLJn.png)

Comment: please share code for `confirm` function too. Thanks

Comment: I don't have a confirm function. I looked at many online tutorials and they said that this is how you confirm the value of a local storage variable

Comment: check in Chrome debug toolbar in `Local Storage` section if Phone number saving or not.

Comment: I checked by typing localStorage['phoneNumber']; and the console responded with undefined

Answer (score 0):

run below code in `browser console` and check in `localStore` if its there or not.

```
localStorage.setItem('phoneNumber', 123456789 );

var getPhNum = localStorage.getItem('phoneNumber');

confirm("Number is " + getPhNum );
```

Comment: what was the issue ?

Comment: I cant acess the local storage variable from a different file

Comment: if its working for you then can upvote answer. Thanks

Comment: your code to check if localstore is there worked but it didnt really fix my problem